# How to setup log4j 2 in Net Beans?

Tags: java, netbeans, log4j

I am new to log4j 2. Can anyone please help me in setting up log4j 2 in Net Beans.
I have searched everything on the internet and didn't help me.
I have added a log4j properties file in my Net Beans Project and also a sample main program.

**I even added classpath by right-clicking on the project -> properties->Libraries->add jar/folder.**

My question is that whether I need to extract the zip file and add the folder or simply add the zip?

**I have done the both ways but the import statement in the sample program is showing that no package with " org" found.** Can anyone please help me in this.Below links are the screenshots of my sample program and log4j properties file.

[This is my sample program with error showing at import statement:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIHmq.png)

[This is my properties file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzXBc.png)

Please give a very clear step-wise instructions.Thank you.

Comment: I know nothing about NetBeans, but in Eclipse (and I'd say in general) JAR files need to be added to the build path of the project for them to be seen. That's different from adding to the classpath, which only matters at runtime and causes exceptions due to classes not found. In your case the compiler itself cannot see the JAR, so it's not a classpath issue.

Comment: try package log4j;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NetBeans supports log4j,but it is very hard to migrate log4j into Netbeans. For knowing this it took 3 days after searching the entire internet. Please download Eclipse. You can use log4j in eclipse. Eclipse is the only one which is directly built in JAVA. SO it supports more libraries than NetBeans.